# Can angular 2 be used without a router like react?

Tags: angular

One thing I was reading about React a while ago was that it is more light weight than angular1 and it you dont' need a router you can just use react for views.

With angular2, do you still have to use the router or you can just use it like a view layer on a per page basis if you like?

Answer (score 3):

The angular2 router module is optional. For a SPA with no complex domain which normally would be represented in the url you can do without.

Answer (score 1):

If you application have different links for different section / features  … ,you need to use router for:

- Part /section identification on the application
- allow users to bookmark links and share them with others
- SEO

You need also router if you want to protect some part of your application for non-authenticated and non-authorized users.